# how to use stored functions mysql (Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'Right Index' in 'field list')

Tags: mysql, workbench

how to use stored functions mysql

```
drop function if exists finger_name;
DELIMITER \\
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `finger_name`(finger_id INT) 
RETURNS `VARCHAR`(45) CHARSET `utf8`
BEGIN
DECLARE NAME `varchar`(45);
CASE finger_id
    WHEN 1 THEN
SET NAME= `Right Thumb`;
    WHEN 2 THEN
SET NAME= `Right Index`;
    WHEN 3 THEN
SET NAME= `Right Middle`;
ELSE
SET NAME= `Not Registered`;
END CASE;
RETURN NAME;
END\\ 
delimiter ;

SELECT FINGER_NAME(2);
```

Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'Right Index' in 'field list

Comment: Please describe the error or problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are setting a string literal in a variable, you should use `single quote` and not `backtick` -- they are used for identifiers such as table name, column names, etc...

```
CASE finger_id
WHEN 1 THEN
    SET NAME= 'Right Thumb';
WHEN 2 THEN
    SET NAME='Right Index';
.....
```

Comment: THANKS... i forget about that.. thanks you for your quick response